# How to avoid Google reCAPTCHA in Selenium tests

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

I have found this doc from Google 
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq
where was written
"You will always get No CAPTCHA and all verification requests will pass.

Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI

Secret key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe"

My question is: how set these keys - values in my Selenium tests?
I have written this code, but it doesn't work, the captcha still present

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("Site key", "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI");
options.setCapability("Secret key","6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You don't

Those keys are for the site, not for the automation script.

When configuring reCAPTCHA to work on a website, each site has it's own set of keys. If the website owner sets the public and private keys to the values you have, it disables the validation. It's used for non-production testing.

If you you wish to perform automation on the website, you will have to contact the website owner about creating a non-public copy of the site and installing those tester keys.

Comment: Thank you. May be explanation of my problem was not so clear... I need avoid captcha when autotest open www.google.com. Is there any possibilities to avoid this captcha, before main google page ? I'm doing task for job interview)

Comment: @IgorVlasuyk, the whole purpose of CAPTCHA is to prevent automated tools. Your explanation is fine. What you are trying to do will not work. You can't insert testing keys into a functioning website via automation. If you could, there would be no reason for the CAPTCHA in the first place.